# Setup mikepenz/fastAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fastadapter

I am trying to implement [mikepenz/fastAdapter](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter) and I dont understand it from the github page. He is using [butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) which I also never used before. Can anyone explain to me what I have to do to setup a sample recycler view with this adapter. Also some sample code might help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you understood mikepenz's fastAdapter? Still need help?

Comment: I have not but i dont have much time to learn it right now so i will focus on that in a few months. Pls still keep me updated if you find a good source to learn it :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this, it's support everything your need for recycler view:

https://github.com/CymChad/BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper

the setup is simpler than the original adapter too:

```
public class QuickAdapter extends BaseQuickAdapter<Status, BaseViewHolder> {
public QuickAdapter() {
    super(R.layout.tweet, DataServer.getSampleData());
}

@Override
protected void convert(BaseViewHolder viewHolder, Status item) {
    viewHolder.setText(R.id.tweetName, item.getUserName())
            .setText(R.id.tweetText, item.getText())
            .setText(R.id.tweetDate, item.getCreatedAt())
            .setVisible(R.id.tweetRT, item.isRetweet())
            .linkify(R.id.tweetText);
             Glide.with(mContext).load(item.getUserAvatar()).crossFade().into((ImageView) viewHolder.getView(R.id.iv));
}
```

}

Comment below if you still need me to demonstrate mikepenz's FastAdapter :D